# Are WAGO lever splice connectors approved for use with solid aluminum #12 or #10 with WAGO joint compound

Tags: electrical, code-compliance, connectors

Are WAGO lever connectors approved for use in the US with #12 and #10 solid aluminum wire with the WAGO joint compound. The use would be for copper pigtailing of aluminum wiring.

Comment: You might want to revise this to ask about specific connectors by part number.  The first and only one I looked up the data for was approved for copper only.  It seems WAGO has a website that very specific, you should be able to find this information.

Comment: Thanks for looking this up. I finally found the information in the WAGO online catalog. Copper only for WAGO 222- and limited to 12AWG which would exclude its use for pigtailing 20-A circuits with 10 AWG aluminum.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found it in the WAGO online catalog WAGO 222-413 lever connector is listed for copper. There is no reference to aluminum. WAGO sells a joint compound in a syringe for injecting into these connectors and this made me hope that they were listed for solid aluminum, but it seems not so. I think it would work, but if it's not listed then one cannot use it for pigtailing aluminum wiring.

[WAGO 222-413](https://eshop.wago.com/JPBC/0_5StartPage.jsp;jsessionid=F7BEA736BDD7F62D2CCB0114520E402D?supplierAID=222-413&catalogID=WAGO01&zone=7)